# Journey-Reentry for Salesforce Data Events using UPDATE

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We run a Journey with SF Data Entry Event based on a fields update. Journey is set to re-entry every time. However: The journey is only triggered when the field is updated for the first time, all updates that are done later times, doesn't get triggered. Is this a common behavior?

Comment: Do you have any filter criteria? If yes, the update needs to set this field from a non-matching value to a matching one.

Comment: Yes there is a filter. How does that update needs to be done?

Comment: Assuming you have a Checkbox field "SFMC_Trigger", a text field named "Some_Text" and a filter for "SFMC_Trigger = True". Then if you set the "SFMC_Trigger" from False to True and the Journey is triggered. If you now update the "Some_Text" field to any value and "SFMC_Trigger" is still True, the journey isn't triggered.

Comment: Ok, just tested it, to re-enter the journey, the record must unmatch the filter criteria to be fired on the next match

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant. Do you mind if I summarize this as an answer and you accept it, so others can easily identify the correct answer without having to read the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined filter criteria a record only matches if the field is changed from a value that isn't matched by your criteria to one that is matched.

**Short example:**

Assuming you have a the following fields:

- Checkbox field "SFMC_Trigger"
- Text field named "Some_Text"

And configured a filter matching **"SFMC_Trigger = True"**.

Setting "SFMC_Trigger" from False to True will trigger the journey. Now updating the "Some_Text" field to any value without changing "SFMC_Trigger" (which then still is set to True) won't trigger the journey. For the journey to trigger again you need to unset "SFMC_Trigger" first. A subsequent update setting it back to True will fire the journey again.